# following error occured while running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/himself/Desktop/image_resizer_bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from telegram import Update, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
ImportError: cannot import name 'Update' from 'telegram' (/home/himself/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/__init__.py)
```

How to fix this?

I was expecting error free code.

Comment: (1) Show "the code" properly formatted in the question. (2) Format the traceback properly (as code).

Comment: What is the `telegram` package you are importing from? Is it you own package, or e.g., https://github.com/alexander-akhmetov/python-telegram or something else?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have installed [`python-telegram`](https://github.com/alexander-akhmetov/python-telegram) when in fact you wanted to install [`python-telegram-bot`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot), which are different packages. Try doing:

```
pip uninstall python-telegram
pip install python-telegram-bot
```

and then re-running your code.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're using an old/ abandoned package. try

`pip install python-telegram-bot`